# Unable to start Kodi

Tags: 16.04, kodi

I have installed the latest Version of Kodi (xbmc). I have  installed/uninstalled/re-installed it several times.

Whenever I'm trying to open it nothing happens (see the error log below). Even though I can see Kodis icon (indicating it's running) in the launcher. Can anyone help me?

Log File

```
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: special://profile/ is mapped to: special://masterprofile/
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Starting Kodi (17.0 Git:20170210-nogitfound). Platform: Linux x86 64-bit
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Using Release Kodi x64 build
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Kodi compiled Nov  4 2012 by GCC 5.4.0 for Linux x86 64-bit version 4.4.40 (263208)
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Running on Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, kernel: Linux x86 64-bit version 4.8.0-39-generic
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: FFmpeg version/source: ffmpeg-3.1-kodi
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Host CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz, 4 cores available
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: special://xbmc/ is mapped to: /usr/share/kodi
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: special://xbmcbin/ is mapped to: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kodi
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: special://xbmcbinaddons/ is mapped to: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kodi/addons
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: special://masterprofile/ is mapped to: /home/mbkm/.kodi/userdata
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: special://envhome/ is mapped to: /home/mbkm
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: special://home/ is mapped to: /home/mbkm/.kodi
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: special://temp/ is mapped to: /home/mbkm/.kodi/temp
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: special://logpath/ is mapped to: /home/mbkm/.kodi/temp
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: The executable running is: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/kodi/kodi.bin
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Local hostname: mbkm-ThinkPad-X240
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Log File is located: /home/mbkm/.kodi/temp//kodi.log
15:05:44.942 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: -----------------------------------------------------------------------
15:05:44.955 T:139935054596480   ERROR: DBus: Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs - No such property 'OnLowBattery'
15:05:44.957 T:139935054596480   ERROR: DBus: Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs - No such property 'CanSuspend'
15:05:44.957 T:139935054596480   ERROR: DBus: Error org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs - No such property 'CanHibernate'
15:05:44.960 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: load settings...
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Found 1 Lists of Devices
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Enumerated PULSE devices:
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:     Device 1
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : Default
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Default
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra: Default Output Device (PULSEAUDIO)
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_channels        : FL,FR
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates     : 5512,8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,64000,88200,96000,176400,192000,384000
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     : AE_FMT_U8,AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S24NE3,AE_FMT_S24NE4,AE_FMT_S32NE,AE_FMT_FLOAT
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_streamTypes     : No passthrough capabilities
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:     Device 2
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : alsa_output.pci-0000_00_03.0.hdmi-stereo
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Built-in Audio Digital Stereo (HDMI)
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra: HDMI / DisplayPort (PULSEAUDIO)
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_channels        : FL,FR
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates     : 5512,8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,64000,88200,96000,176400,192000,384000
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     : AE_FMT_U8,AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S24NE3,AE_FMT_S24NE4,AE_FMT_S32NE,AE_FMT_FLOAT
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_streamTypes     : No passthrough capabilities
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:     Device 3
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_deviceName      : alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_displayName     : Built-in Audio Analog Stereo
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_displayNameExtra: Headphones (PULSEAUDIO)
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_deviceType      : AE_DEVTYPE_PCM
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_channels        : FL,FR
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_sampleRates     : 5512,8000,11025,16000,22050,32000,44100,48000,64000,88200,96000,176400,192000,384000
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_dataFormats     : AE_FMT_U8,AE_FMT_S16NE,AE_FMT_S24NE3,AE_FMT_S24NE4,AE_FMT_S32NE,AE_FMT_FLOAT
15:05:44.971 T:139935054596480  NOTICE:         m_streamTypes     : No passthrough capabilities
15:05:44.974 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: No settings file to load (special://xbmc/system/advancedsettings.xml)
15:05:44.974 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: No settings file to load (special://masterprofile/advancedsettings.xml)
15:05:44.974 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Default Video Player: VideoPlayer
15:05:44.974 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Default Audio Player: paplayer
15:05:44.974 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Disabled debug logging due to GUI setting. Level 0.
15:05:44.974 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Log level changed to "LOG_LEVEL_NORMAL"
15:05:44.974 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: CMediaSourceSettings: loading media sources from special://masterprofile/sources.xml
15:05:44.974 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Loading player core factory settings from special://xbmc/system/playercorefactory.xml.
15:05:44.974 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Loaded playercorefactory configuration
15:05:44.974 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: Loading player core factory settings from special://masterprofile/playercorefactory.xml.
15:05:44.974 T:139935054596480  NOTICE: special://masterprofile/playercorefactory.xml does not exist. Skipping.
15:05:44.978 T:139935054596480   ERROR: SQL: [Addons27.db] SQL error or missing database
                                            Query: SELECT idVersion FROM version
```

Comment: The problem is at a profile level and one or more addons is probably the culprit. Reinstalling changes nothing. Deleting the hidden folder `.kodi` should do it. Be aware this resets Kodi settings.

Comment: As CelticWarrior suggested. And... did you have Kodi 16.1 installed and working before? If not, do you have MySQL installed?

Comment: @CelticWarrior thank you for your help!! and thank you, everyone for your support

Comment: @CelticWarrior maybe post an answer?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is at a profile level and one or more addons is probably the culprit. Reinstalling changes nothing because the user profile settings, addons, etc. is kept.

Deleting the hidden folder `.kodi` should do it.

Be aware this will reset all Kodi settings.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the last line of the log you have

```
15:05:44.978 T:139935054596480   ERROR: SQL: [Addons27.db] SQL error 
or missing database
    Query: SELECT idVersion FROM version
```

This indicates that Kodi failed trying to query the table `version` from the database `Addons27.db`

There seems to be a problem with your database, which you can find in `userdata/Database/`. Normally the error would reference mysql if you were using it.

The simplest workaround is to delete `Addons27.db` from `userdata/Database`. This would delete your addons database but all other configurations, including sources, library, addons packages and configurations, would be kept as is. If you have a backup of `Addons27.db` (you should keep backups of the Database folder anyways - I personnally backup the whole kodi user folder), you can always revert to a working copy.

The reason why deleting the whole `.kodi` directory works is in doing so, you are also deleting the faulty `Addons27.db`, while also deleting all other settings, which is why I prefer to only delete the faulty file.